# How to change activity layout through swipeable tabs android java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tabs

In my android application I have two `.xaml` layouts like `activity_1` and `activity_2` and I want to change these layout's activity through 2 swipeable tabs because after that i want to add more tabs: and below is my activity:

```
package com.example.hakslogin;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class LoginSuccess extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final String LOG_TAG = "SlidingTabsBasicFragment";
    private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_success);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login_success, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

       class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            /**
             * @return the number of pages to display
             */
            @Override
           /* public int getCount() {  //I am not using this method
                return 5;
            }*/

            /**
             * @return true if the value returned from
             *         {@link #instantiateItem(ViewGroup, int)} is the same object
             *         as the {@link View} added to the {@link ViewPager}.
             */
            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
                return o == view;
            }

            @Override
            /*public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { //I am not using this //method because I am giving name of tabs in SlidingTabLayout.java class
                return pageTitle + " " + (position + 1);  
            }*/ 

            // END_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)

            /**
             * Instantiate the {@link View} which should be displayed at
             * {@code position}. Here we inflate a layout from the apps resources
             * and then change the text view to signify the position.
             */
            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                // Inflate a new layout from our resources
                View view  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_login_success,
                            container, false);
                    container.addView(view);

                    // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
                    // --comment by me
                    //TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                    //title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "instantiateItem() [position: " + position + "]");

                return view;
            }

            /**
             * Destroy the item from the {@link ViewPager}. In our case this is
             * simply removing the {@link View}.
             */
            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((View) object);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroyItem() [position: " + position + "]");
            }

        }
}
```

And I am doing above the same code into my another activity like below:

```
package com.example.hakslogin;

import com.example.android.common.view.SlidingTabLayout;

import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AddChildActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    static final String LOG_TAG = "SlidingTabsBasicFragment";
    private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_child);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_child, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        /*@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }*/

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
            return o == view;
        }

        /*@Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return pageTitle + " " + (position + 1);
        }*/

        // END_INCLUDE (pageradapter_getpagetitle)

        /**
         * Instantiate the {@link View} which should be displayed at
         * {@code position}. Here we inflate a layout from the apps resources
         * and then change the text view to signify the position.
         */
        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            // Inflate a new layout from our resources
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_add_child,
                        container, false);
                container.addView(view);

                // Retrieve a TextView from the inflated View, and update it's text
                // --comment by me
                //TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
                //title.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "instantiateItem() [position: " + position + "]");
                return view;
        }
        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((View) object);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "destroyItem() [position: " + position + "]");
        }

    }
}
```

and below is `SlidingTabLayout.java` class:

```
package com.example.android.common.view;


import com.example.hakslogin.LoginSuccess;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

    /**
     * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
     * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
     */
    public interface TabColorizer {

        /**
         * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
         */
        int getIndicatorColor(int position);

        /**
         * @return return the color of the divider drawn to the right of {@code position}.
         */
        int getDividerColor(int position);

    }

    private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
    private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

    private int mTitleOffset;

    private int mTabViewLayoutId;
    private int mTabViewTextViewId;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;
    String value = "";
    private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;
   // public  SlidingTabLayout() {

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    //}

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        // Disable the Scroll Bar
        setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
        setFillViewport(true);

        mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

        mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
        addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
     *
     * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
     * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} and {@link #setDividerColors(int...)} to achieve
     * similar effects.
     */
    public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
        mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
     * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the colors to be used for tab dividers. These colors are treated as a circular array.
     * Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
     */
    public void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
        mTabStrip.setDividerColors(colors);
    }

    /**
     * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
     * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
     * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
     *
     * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
     */
    public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
        mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
     *
     * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
     * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
     */
    public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
        mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
        mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
     * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
     */
    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

        mViewPager = viewPager;
        if (viewPager != null) {
            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
            populateTabStrip();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
     * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
     */

    protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
        textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the Theme's
            // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed state
            TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
            getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                    outValue, true);
            textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
            //textView.setAllCaps(true);
            //textView.setAllCaps(true);
        }

        int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

        return textView;
    }

    String names[] = {"Home","Add Child"};//,"Add Item", "Questions", "Answer"};
    int len = names.length;
    private void populateTabStrip() {
        final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
        final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

        for (int i = 0; i < names.length ; i++) {// i++) {;adapter.getCount()
            View tabView = null;
            TextView tabTitleView = null;

            if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
                // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
                tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                        false);
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
            }

            if (tabView == null) {
                tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
            }

            if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
                tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
            }
            LoginSuccess.pageTitle = names[i].toString();
            tabTitleView.setText(names[i].toString());//adapter.getPageTitle(i)
            tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

            mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        if (mViewPager != null) {
            scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
        }
    }

    private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
        final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
            return;
        }

        View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
        if (selectedChild != null) {
            int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

            if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
                // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
                targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
            }

            scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
        }
    }

    private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private int mScrollState;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
            if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
                return;
            }

            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

            View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
            int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                    ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                    : 0;
            scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                        positionOffsetPixels);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            mScrollState = state;

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
                scrollToTab(position, 0);
            }

            if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
                mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
            }
        }

    }

    private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
                if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am using this [link](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html), and its show me two tabs on any first activity but the problem is that its show layout multiple times one on my activity layout and on sliding page layout, Kindly suggest me what can I handle it, waiting for reply Thanks.